# How can i get all posts by a particular user in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Try to get all post's by a user in application and show in a table with corresponding column , i tried with this way but showing exception : " Trying to get property of non-object " , how to solve it ?

```
public function usersPost(){
$uid = \Auth::user()->id;
$posts = DB::table('posts')->('user_id',$uid);
}
```

Here two table posts and users and user_id is foreign key of posts table .

Answer (score 6):

Laravel allows you to relate models to each other. For instance, you can relate your Post model to your User model like this.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }

}
```

After specifying that the User has many posts through a One-to-Many relationship, you can then simply call all of your user's posts.

```
$posts = User::find(user_id)->posts;
```

Comment: instead of `user_id` what if I want to search for name field

Comment: @VivekPadhye This would be as simple as User::where('name', 'John')->first()->posts;

Answer (score 4):

```
public function usersPost() {
    $posts = DB::table('posts')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->get();
}
```

Comment: yap thanks your code is worked @joseph silber
how can i use paginate() here ??

Answer (score 2):

You need a where clause like this:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')->where('user_id', $uid)->get();
```

Comment: Only if the data isn't relational. If it is (which it should be) then you can simply use what I mentioned in my answer.